# Dropdown menu opens behind the next <div>

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

This is my question about the dropdown menu which open behind the div.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
 <div style="position:relative; left:0px; top:0px;">

     <div style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
              <div class="styled-select">
                     <select id="campaignListId" name="campaignId" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" style="z-index:99999">
                        <option value="1">First</option>
                        <option value="2">Second</option>
                        <option value="3">Third</option>
                        <option value="4">Fourth</option>
                        <option value="5">Fifth</option>
                        <option value="6">Sixth</option>
                        <option value="7">Seventh</option>
                        <option value="8">Eighth</option>
                        <option value="9">Ninth</option>
                        <option value="10">Tenth</option>
                    </select>
              </div>

              <div style="background-color: grey; width: 100%; height:400px; left: 0px; ">
                    <div style="width: 944px;  margin: 0 auto; ">
                         <font style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold; ">
                            <span id="spanMOV" style="cursor: pointer; color: #4F9DD0; text-decoration: underline; " >
                                Movies
                            </span>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span id="spanGAM" style="cursor: pointer;" >
                                Games
                            </span>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span id="spanRES" style="cursor: pointer;" >
                                Restaurant
                            </span>
                    </div>
              </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**And this is my CSS code:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .styled-select select {
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        width: 944px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        color: #4F9DD0;
        line-height: 1;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -o-appearance: none;
    }
    .styled-select {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
        background-color: white;
        width: 944px; 
        height: 48px;
        position: relative;  
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

The problem is that, whenever I click on the select dropdown, it opens behind the `<div>` after that. I had tried z-index but it did not work.

Comment: @ketan I mentioned at the beginning that I asked and was solved partially.

Comment: Check the comment there. Where it is mention to remove `position:relative`

Comment: @ketan Yes, and I voted up your answer there, but the problem was that adding the new div, and also removing the "position" it still shifts up, this is your code, look here: https://jsfiddle.net/v2xu2801/5/
but really thanks your answer helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.styled-select` and it shows up infront of it. If you want it to have a white background then, you need to change `background: transparent` on `.styled-select select` to `background: white`.

Answer (score 1):

Try after removing position:relative.

```
.styled-select {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    background-color: white;
    width: 944px; 
    height: 48px;
    /*position: relative;  */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

OR

```
.styled-select {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background: url(resources/img/campaignSelector.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
    background-color: white;
    width: 944px; 
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Its works for me.